# regeneration system Script timeout: exhausted allowed execution time

Tags: lua, roblox

so I'm trying to create a regeneration system for my game In Roblox I'm having problems with the Script this is the script:

```
task.wait(10)
game.Workspace.CoreGame:Destroy()
task.wait(10)
game.ServerStorage.Map.CoreGame:Clone().Parent=workspace
print("DONE!")
```

it's giving me the Error “Script timeout: exhausted allowed execution time” even though there is no Loop At all I've looked for days trying to figure out a solution but I couldn't find any info about the problem I'm having here is a picture of the error:

[image: Error]

it always says it on the last line of the script no matter what is in it I Have Tryed to limit how much stuff is in the CoreGame folder and still did not work

limiting stuff in the folder
putting the folder in a different area
cloning the folder instead of using :Destroy()

Comment: How large is `game.ServerStorage.Map.CoreGame`? It appears that cloning and moving all of those objects is causing the script to timeout

Comment: Very big unfortunately. I cannot limit the size as I've limited it as much as I can already. Considering most of the scripts, values And Sounds are in that folder and there is a lot of them is there any other way I could do it or do I have to limit the size even more.